# Handler() in onRefresh() during Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, refresh, swiperefreshlayout

So I have this `ListView` which I'd like to scroll down and refresh. I am using `SwipeRefreshLayout` and it's working pretty well, except I can't arrange the time that the `Handler` in the `onRefresh()` method should wait. So here's my `onRefresh()`

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    final String net = getString(R.string.alertin);
    final String netErr = getString(R.string.alert_intext);
    ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ntwrkInf = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ntwrkInf != null && ntwrkInf .isConnected()) {
        ListReq refList = new ListReq();
        refList.execute();
    } else {
        AlertDialogDisp(Main.this, net, netErr);
    }       
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 5000); // so it's here, I just put 5000 randomly.
}
```

and as you would expect 5000 is not the right amount for my `Asynctask` to finish its job. How can I arrange this and get the 'refreshing animation' to finish as the Asynctask ends?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) override the method `onPostExecute()`. This method is called when your AsyncTask complete his tasks.

It will be something like this:

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> {

protected void doInBackground(Void ...) {
    //Your process
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void...) {
    //Call your onRefresh()
}
```

Comment: but I have one last question, if I call my onRefresh() in onPostExecute() won't it try to execute the asynctask all over again?

Comment: Remove the `Handler()` from your onRefresh() you don't need it anymore. And the `postExecute()` is called once after you `AsyncTask` has finish his job

Comment: okay, but what I am asking is, I execute my asynctask from my onRefresh() method, and when I call onRefresh() in onPostExecute, won't it try to execute the asynctask all over again?

Comment: Of course it will execute it! You can avoid it by implementing a condition depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

In AsynkTask is method postExecute() it will be called when you AsynkTask finish its job. 
So just meke a asynk call to inform in right time. Without arbiraly set it to 5000

Comment: uhmm, what do you mean? What will be called when my AsyncTask finishes its job? I can't calculate the exact time the Asynctask is gonna take on my own since it contains data sending and receiving.

Comment: @pskink I have seen it already and I don't see how I can retreive the time of my asynctask from there?

Comment: why do you need that time?

Comment: @pskink as I have said in my question, in order to set the time for my onRefresh() to last

Comment: see when onPostExecute is called